# My node app with valid syntax is failing silently, but not breaking. Infrastructure problem?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I built a simple Node app, and the code "works", with no failures, no syntax errors, and does not break, but one component doesn't work right. I showed a snippet [on Stack Overflow, in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444848/function-failing-silently-with-perfect-syntax-how-should-i-debug?noredirect=1#comment34136300_22444848), but viewers found no issue. So, I think the infrastructure, the method, in which I put this app together must be problematic, and I'd like to have it reviewed.

I put everything into a single source file to eliminate the headache of debugging whilst keeping track of modules.

[Here is the code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9592099)

Here's my relevant script:

```
var connection = createConnection();

connection.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) return callback(new Error('Failed to connect'), null);
    console.log('[Post]Connection with the officeball MySQL database opened...');

    connection.query(
        'INSERT INTO `officeball`.`sales_entries` SET category = ?, `group` = ?, date = ?, price = ?, customer = ?, seller = ?, commission = ?',
    salesData),

    function (err, rows, fields) {

        if (err) console.log(err);
        connection.destroy();
        console.log('[Post]...Connection with the officeball MySQL database closed.');

    }
});
```

And here's my console output:

```
Application initializing...
Application successfully initialized!
Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/
User username1 is attempting to validate for a hit...
Connection with the Officeball MySQL database openned...
...Connection with the Officeball MySQL database closed.
User username1 validated and is ready!
[Post] Connection with the officeball MySQL database opened...
```

Comment: Code review is a site for posting code to be reviewed, not for posting links to code you want reviewed.  While it's okay to post a link to the full project, at a minimum, you should include the code you most want reviewed in your question, for numerous reasons.

Comment: Sure, sorry, I'm new. I'll add the snippet. @nhgrif

Comment: Also, I'd like to add that this is my first non-tutorial node app, and while I understand the efficiency and power of Node's callback functions, I'm focusing on a working application more than I am on one that can handle a billion users right now. Please keep that in mind when performing your review. Also, thank you ahead of time. I appreciate this.

Comment: And Jamal, thank you for that edit. I've seen you around the exchange more than a few times so far.

Answer (score 3):

From a once over:

- Your `console.log` statement should be wrapped in a condition so that you can turn off all logging to the console. Node can really slow down because of logging to the console.
- If you are going to log to the console, then it would make more sense to log your query and `salesData` as well.
- Opening and closing a connection every time you want to post a sale is (very) bad practice, check out `mysql.createPool`
- Calling `connection.end();` will kill a connection gracefully. calling `connection.destroy()`, not so much..

All in all, I would always be sensitive to performance and established best practice.

Comment: Thanks Konijn, those are very good points. I did not know that console logs could slow the execution down. Mainly though, I need to look into that connection pooling.